# How to create a build.xml for a project that has multiple directories?

Tags: linux, ant, build.xml

I have a Java project with the current directory structure:
Classes
Jars
Properties
Config

Each of these folders have some files which when I run make creates a project.

Now I have added another folder named client, which has two sub-folders: sampleRequests and YANG, along with one or two more files.

I do not know how to change my build.xml so that it incorporates the client folder and the sub-directories too. 
I already have the build.xml for the earlier code where ai am copying my files. So lets say if I am using $out_dir for my project folder, can I simply use $out_dir/client/sampleRequests for this. Or the format is totally different. Stuck in a limbo. Please help.

Comment: Do makefiles in fact come into this at all?

Comment: No I just added it to tell what I am doing

Comment: If makefiles don't come into it then adding that tag *obscures* what you're actually doing.  Edited.

Comment: A [mre] would make this a lot clearer, but there are almost always multiple alternatives.  You can use the form `$out_dir/client/sampleRequests` to designate subdirectories relative to `$out_dir`, but we have no basis to judge whether that would be the best or most appropriate alternative for you.